# How to dockerize spring cloud gateway and eureka server and link with keycloak?

Tags: docker, microservices, keycloak, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

I am new with docker. how to dockerize spring cloud gateway (is its image available in docker hub or not),eureka server and link with keycloak? I am getting problem in this.

The problem is I don't whether I have to dockerize my gateway application or use docker image (if available) and confogure that?

Comment: Don't you think mentioning the problem you're getting would be useful?